# Sort SQL records based on matched conditions

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key LIKE '1,2,3,%' OR key LIKE '1,2,%' OR key LIKE '1,%'
```

Is it posible to sort records returned from this query based on which conditions was matched first. I'd like to get all records that match `key LIKE '1,2,3,%'` first, then `key LIKE '1,2,%'` and the others after.

For example, if I have these records:

```
key: "1,2,3,4"
key: "1,2,5"
key: "1,4"
key: "1,2,5,6"
key: "1,3"
key: "1,2,3,4,7"
key: "1,2,4"
```

I would like them to be sorted like so:

```
key: "1,2,3,4"
key: "1,2,3,4,7"
key: "1,2,4"
key: "1,2,5"
key: "1,2,5,6"
key: "1,3"
key: "1,4"
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Notice it's just normal lexical string sorting...

Comment: Your query is redundant. using just "WHERE key LIKE '1,%'" will give you the same results.

Comment: @Kevin, yes you are absolutely right. Since I'm now using the more specific conditions in the "ORDER BY CASE", I've now changed my WHERE condition to only "1,%".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.... ORDER BY CASE

  WHEN key LIKE '1,2,3,%' THEN 1

  WHEN key LIKE '1,2,%' THEN 2

  ELSE 3

  END`

Comment: I would use this as it is familiar to me.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I used. It seems to me that using a full-text search is a bit too resource-heavy for this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`MATCH ... AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) and order by rank. It exactly does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Does using "UNION" could do the job?

SELECT * FROM table WHERE key LIKE '1,2,3,%' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key LIKE '1,2,%' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key LIKE key LIKE '1,%'